# Exception while executing unit test cases - Could not self-attach to current VM using external process

Tags: android, android-studio, junit, mockito

I am getting this error in the android studio since the last two days when I run any test cases.

Here are the error logs.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not self-attach to current VM using external process
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.installExternal(ByteBuddyAgent.java:675)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:606)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:586)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:538)
    at net.bytebuddy.agent.ByteBuddyAgent.install(ByteBuddyAgent.java:515)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.JvmMockKAgentFactory.initInstrumentation(JvmMockKAgentFactory.kt:134)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.JvmMockKAgentFactory.init(JvmMockKAgentFactory.kt:34)
    at io.mockk.impl.JvmMockKGateway.<init>(JvmMockKGateway.kt:46)
```

I have tried the below solutions but unfortunately nothing works for me.

1. Invalid cache and restart
2. Clear gradle cache and restart Tried
3. following commands in terminal

```
rm -rfv ~/Library/Application Support/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio*
rm -rfv ~/.AndroidStudio*
```

4. Changed the JDK versions(Currently using 11.0.13)
5. Tried with older versions of android studio

Can anyone help me to fix this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i got the solution to set the below line in **.bash_profile** in my mac.

```
export JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true"
```

Answer (score 2):

This JVM option works for me in gradle build by adding following in build.gradle file.

`test { jvmArgs "-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true" }`

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this only when running tests with this added to the gradle configuration:

```
android {
  ...
  testOptions {
    ...
    unitTests.all {
      it.jvmArgs("-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i found that the issue was coming from the mockk dependency,
so i upgraded the version from `testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.13.2'`
to `testImplementation 'io.mockk:mockk:1.13.3'` and synced, and my tests works fine again,

hope this helps someone